# copying file from temp directory to resource folder

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am able to record a .caf file in my app and play it back to the user. I want to be able save it permanently so I want to move it to my resources folder. I am not sure if this is the correct move or whether it would be better to put it in the documents directory but I access all my other sound files from resource so I assumed this would be the right choice. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

How I save the recording to temp:

```
NSURL *soundFileURL=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:
                         [NSTemporaryDirectory()
                          stringByAppendingString:@"soundFile1.caf"]];
```

Comment: what do u mean by resource folder?

Comment: Like the resource folder you see in Xcode where all images and things like sound files are. Except I would like to do this programteically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add, remove or modify files in your application bundle, which means you can't add items to the resources directory.

If the file is something the user will want to keep in the app, it should be stored in the documents directory. You may want to prevent it being backed up to iCloud, which you can do by following [Apple's instructions here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html).

To get a path to the documents directory, or the path for a given filename in the documents directory, you can use methods like these:

```
+ (NSString *)pathForDocumentsDirectory
{
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
}

+ (NSString *)pathForFileInDocumentsDirectory:(NSString *)filename
{
    return [[self pathForDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
}
```

Comment: Okay thank you. How would I put into the documents dir instead then?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add anything into your application bundle of your application while using application so add them in document or library folder of application

Comment: Okay thank you. How would I put into the documents dir instead then? Thanks

Comment: @AlexG refer to the answer posted by Mike. that's how you get the documents dir and then just copy or move them over.